# Can I have one HTML table header be over two table columns? Like merge and center in Excel?

Tags: html, html-table, center, tableheader

I want to have one table header be centered over two table columns side by side. Is this possible?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`<th colspan="2">. This .</th>`

To extrapolate a bit...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Single Column</th>
      <th colspan="2">Double Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Column One</td>
      <td>Column Two</td>
      <td>Column Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That should give you enough to work from.

Answer (score 11):

If you only have 2 columns then I would suggest using `<caption>`.  Otherwise, use colspan as suggested in other answers.

```
<table>
  <caption>This will span all columns.</caption>
  <tr><td>column one</td><td>column two</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course. Please refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) page. You are looking for attribute called `colspan` for table headers cells.

Answer (score 4):

We can do it in better way.

```
<table border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">Test Heading</th>
    <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Mars</th>
    <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
    <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Test 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Test 2</th>
    <th scope="col">Test 3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please  visit [Table Ref From w3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/) if you want to know more.