# How to align border of jtable columns with groupable header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jtableheader

i am working on groupable Header in `JTable`. I followed the previous ways mentioned in StackOverFlow and have been able to add groupable header in `JTable` looking at:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm

My problem is that there is an alignment issue between header and column. I want to make both the header and column border in same alignment. As this image shows difference in border of both the header and column:

[image]

Please suggest me what should i do.

Comment: `Please suggest me what should i do.` - You are using custom code you fount on the internet. There YOU need to debug the code you found to figure out why the columns sizes don't match.

Comment: While not a direct answer to you question - I find the solution you've followed to be limited; instead, I [wrote a different version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206578/show-column-header-on-dragging-column/20208995#20208995) which supports many of the features that are now available which weren't when the original version was written (sorting, dragging, etc) - I also agree with Camickr, this is not something we can overly help you with

Answer (score 0):

I did the code change which helped me to resolve the issue . Hope its helps you

In class : GroupableTableHeaderUI

cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin; // Remove the column margin which is adding 1px to the width of the header column

New line will have : cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth()

In class : ColumnGroup

comment line :  // width += margin;

This has helped me to align the table columns and the header column . Please find below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzOQY.png)

Answer (score -1):

*BorderLayout.CENTER* is the simple answer, but notice if you want to add more than one item (which is typically the case) then you must understand that when using BORDERLAYOUT.NORTH for example there must exist an object that has a layout of BORDERLAYOUT.SOUTH in that case JAVA understands that these object are on top of each other , same applies to EAST and WEST