# Personnal header on object herited from jXTable

Tags: java, swing

In my project, I have to replace use of JTable by an object herited from jXTable.

Current code:

```
 JTable jt= new JTable(myModel) {
       @Override
          public void createDefaultColumnsFromModel() {
            super.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
            setTableHeader(createDefaultTableHeader());
          }
       }
```

What I want to do is:

```
 PersoJxTable jt= new PersoJxTable (myModel) {
           @Override
              public void createDefaultColumnsFromModel() {
                super.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
                setTableHeader(createDefaultTableHeader());
              }
           }
```

PersoJxTable herited from jxTable.

Problem:  createDefaultColumnsFromModel  is already  overriden by jXtable as final method and I can't override it anymore.
Comment says I have to use ColumnFactory but I can't understand how it works.

Can someone help me to have a personnal header on my object herited from jXTable?

Comment: `Can someone help me to have a personnal header on my object herited from jXTable?` - why do you think you need a personal header. The header is just created from the values contained in the "column names" of your TableModel. If you want custom names then specify the proper names when you create the model.

Comment: Hi, I look for a personal header because I need ColumnGroups. For example : I need column 1 and 2 to be under group A, column 3, 4,5 to be under group B

Comment: `I need ColumnGroups` - so that is your requirement. Be explicit when you ask a question so we don't have to guess what you are aksing. "Group" is the keyword to use when searching. Here is  question I found in the forum on the topic that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871309/merged-header-above-a-jtable-header-in-java/9872323#9872323